# Spring security shares context between multiple threads, how can I avoid this?

Tags: spring, spring-security, jwt

I have been working on a spring-based service, using JWT for authentication.

The service handling the user requests calls an authorization service in a filter which sets up the security context and looks pretty much like this :

```
@Component
public class TokenAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Autowired
    private AuthorizationServiceClient authorizationServiceClient;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            User user = authorizationServiceClient.requestUserFromToken(request.getHeader("X-Auth-Token"));
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(new UserAuthentication(user));
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(null);
        } catch (HttpClientErrorException e) {
            response.sendError(e.getStatusCode().value());
        }
    }
}
```

The AuthorizationServiceClient calls a remote service which handles the validation of the user's role and credentials.

I have been facing a very strange behavior :

When a page on my UI was making multiple request simultaneously, I end up getting a 500, caused by a NullPointerException.

The root cause is the Principal (containing the identity of the user) being null, when it shouldn't have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a painful investigation, I ended figuring that the SecurityContextHolder, even though it was using a ThreadLocal, was using sessions, and then would be shared between the threads.

The `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(null);` was erasing the value used in concurrent threads when some requests were made in the same session, and was leading to the NPE.

So, if like me, you'd like to prevent the use of the sessions, you need to set up the security using :

```
http.
    [...]
    .sessionManagement()
    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).
    [...]
```